# I want to make a directory with a variable Path

Tags: mkdir, chararray

I want to make a directory with a variable Path but it only works, if I put the name of the directory in quotation marks. But then the name of the directory isn't variable anymore. I can't find any solution for that. I want that the variable inside `datei22` should get the name and path of the directory. `datei22` is a char array.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by variable path?